# Genus of Edwards curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, plane-curves

Let us work over a field $\Bbbk$ of characteristic not equal to two. Let $d\in\Bbbk\setminus\{0,1\}$. It is said in [the wikipedia article about Edwards curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwards_curve) that the plane *quartic* defined by the equation
$$x^2+y^2 = 1 + d\cdot x^2y^2$$
is birationally equivalent to a curve in Weierstraß form, i.e. a plane *cubic*. However, the genus of a plane curve of degree $d$ is equal to
$$g(d)=\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}.$$
Furthermore, the genus is a birational invariant and $g(4)=3\ne 1=g(3)$. How can it be that the Edwards curve is birationally equivalent to a cubic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression you have written down is the genus of a *nonsingular* plane projective curve. The projective closure of the Edwards curve in $\mathbf P^2$ is not smooth!

Comment: d'uh. Indeed. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Marie, do you think I should change my user name to Georgette?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I think Georges is a beautiful name, but sometimes we all need a bit of extra spice in our lives!

Comment: Dear Marie, thanks for your flattering answer! Needless to say, my question was tongue-in-cheek but the feminine version Georgette of Georges really existed in France and was discontinued, I would guess, about 60 years ago. Since first names have a sort of cyclic existence, I can't exclude the possibility that Georgette will be all the rage in trendy families in a few years  ... That'll be the day! [By the way,+1 for your answer].

Comment: Thank you @GeorgesElencwajg! I know exactly what you are talking about: one of my grandmothers was named Albertine!